# wmi.x_access_denied RDP

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a small script in Python 3 that should make a RDP connection to a Windows Server platform.
We did the same job for Unix machines using an SSH connection and it all went well, but with Windows we can't get out of it.

For now I'm just trying to log in to the computer in RDP and the code is as follows:

#

```
import os
hostname = "172.30.298.172"
response = os.system("ping -a " + hostname)

if response == 0:
  print (hostname, 'is up!')
else:
  print (hostname, 'is down!')


import wmi, time
ip = '172.30.298.172'
username = 'USER\user'
passw = 'password'

print ("Tentativo di connessione verso %s" %ip)
connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=passw)
print ("Connessione stabilita")
print ("Starting IO")
```

#

When we execute the code we receive this error and do not understand the reason:

#

```
Esecuzione di Ping 172.30.298.172 con 32 byte di dati:
Risposta da 172.30.298.172: byte=32 durata=17ms TTL=125
Risposta da 172.30.298.172: byte=32 durata=22ms TTL=125
Risposta da 172.30.298.172: byte=32 durata=16ms TTL=125
Risposta da 172.30.298.172: byte=32 durata=19ms TTL=125

Statistiche Ping per 172.30.298.172:
    Pacchetti: Trasmessi = 4, Ricevuti = 4, 
    Persi = 0 (0% persi),
Tempo approssimativo percorsi andata/ritorno in millisecondi:
    Minimo = 16ms, Massimo =  22ms, Medio =  18ms
172.30.298.172 is up!

Tentativo di connessione verso 172.30.298.172
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Analisi log\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1263, in connect
    authentication_level=authentication_level
  File "C:\Users\user\Analisi log\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1397, in connect_server
    named_value_set
  File "<COMObject WbemScripting.SWbemLocator>", line 5, in ConnectServer
  File "C:\Users\user\Analisi log\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Eccezione.', (0, 'SWbemLocator', 'Accesso negato. ', None, 0, -2147024891), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Analisi log/connessione gateway.py", line 18, in <module>
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=passw)
  File "C:\Users\user\Analisi log\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1290, in connect
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Users\user\Analisi log\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_access_denied: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Eccezione.', (0, 'SWbemLocator', 'Accesso negato. ', None, 0, -2147024891), None)>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

#

Maybe some of you, certainly more experienced, might have some more ideas.

Meanwhile, I thank you for your time.

Hello to all :)